# Java Code is printing white pages

Tags: java, printing

I have to print receipt using Thermal printer Sewoo SLK-TS400. I am making a string and want to print it with printer. But it is printing white pages. I have  already searched many things but nothing happens.

Method for making the bill

```
package printprogram;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class MakingBill {
public static void main(String[] args)
{

  DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
  DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
  Date date = new Date();
  Date time = new Date();
  String Date = dateFormat.format(date);
  String Time = timeFormat.format(time);
  String Header = 
        "   ****Super Market****       \n"
        + "Date: "+Date+"     Time: "+Time+"\n"
        + "---------------------------------\n"
        + "Name          Qty    Rate     Amt\n"
        + "---------------------------------\n";

  String amt  =    
        "\n \n \nTotal Amount = "   +"\n"
        + "Tax ="       + "\n"
        + "*********************************\n"
        + "Thank you. \n";

  String bill = Header;
    System.out.println(bill);

  Main mn = new Main();
  mn.printCard(bill);    
 }
}
```

And the class that print the bill

```
package printprogram;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;

public class Main {

public static void printCard(final String bill) {
    Printable contentToPrint = new Printable() {
        @Override
        public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int page)       throws PrinterException {
            if (page > 0) {
                return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
            }
            pageFormat.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics.create();

            g2d.setPaint(Color.black);
            g2d.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));
            g2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableX());

            g2d.drawString(bill, 0, 0); 

            return PAGE_EXISTS;
        }
    };

    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    job.setPrintable(contentToPrint);
    //You can show a print dialog before printing by job by wrapping the following blocks with a conditional statement if(job.printDialog()){...}
    try {
        job.print();
    } catch (PrinterException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }

  }
}
```

Please help. I am new in java.

Comment: If my answer fixes your problem I would be grateful if you click the tick next to my answer (top left) to show others that question has been answered sufficiently and to let the author of the question (me) know that their answer was correct.

Answer (score 1):

First I would like to say sorry it took so long for someone to answer your question. Now on topic.

There are a few problems with your code but they only occur in `Main.java`

1. Where you have the code `g2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableX());` you call `getImageableX()` twice instead of `g2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY());`.
2. Where you try and draw your string `bill` you seem to be unaware of the fact that `drawString()` is unable to process a new line, `\n`. To fix this you can use [`FontMetrics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html). For example:

   ```
   private void drawString(Graphics g, String text, int x, int y) {
       for (String line : text.split("\n"))
           g.drawString(line, x, y += g.getFontMetrics().getHeight());
   }
   ```

To be sure the code provided below works, I tested it and it prints properly.

---

This leaves you with code which looks like this

**Main.java**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;

public class Main {
    private void drawString(Graphics g, String text, int x, int y) {
        for (String line : text.split("\n"))
            g.drawString(line, x, y += g.getFontMetrics().getHeight());
    }

    public Main(String bill) {
        Printable contentToPrint = new Printable() {
            @Override
            public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int page) throws PrinterException {
                if (page > 0) {
                    return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
                }
                pageFormat.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)graphics;

                g2d.setPaint(Color.black);
                g2d.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));
                g2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY());

                drawString(g2d, bill, 0, 0); 

                return PAGE_EXISTS;
            }
        };

        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        job.setPrintable(contentToPrint);
        try {
            job.printDialog();
            job.print();
        } catch (PrinterException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (HeadlessException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**MakingBill.java**

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class MakingBill {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        Date date = new Date();
        Date time = new Date();
        String Date = dateFormat.format(date);
        String Time = timeFormat.format(time);
        String Header = 
            "   ****Super Market****       \n"
            + "Date: "+Date+"     Time: "+Time+"\n"
            + "---------------------------------\n"
            + "Name          Qty    Rate     Amt\n"
            + "---------------------------------\n";

        String amt  =    
            "\n \n \nTotal Amount = "   +"\n"
            + "Tax ="       + "\n"
            + "*********************************\n"
            + "Thank you. \n";

        String bill = Header;
        System.out.println(bill);

        Main mn = new Main(bill);
    }
}
```

This produces an output which looks like this:

[image: Output]

To make everything line up as you wish either add extra `-` or change the font.